# RequireJs build script failing to locate jQuery

Tags: requirejs, js-amd

I'm successfully loading jQuery (when setting `require.config`)...

```
// For details see: 
// http://groups.google.com/group/requirejs/browse_thread/thread/e7532b7e3013bc62/1e5ca8a89b276de6?show_docid=1e5ca8a89b276de6
require.config({ 
    paths : { 
        'jquery' : 'Utils/jquery' 
    } 
});
```

I have a github repo with the entire set-up here: https://github.com/Integralist/RequireJs-Example

My issue is that when I try to run the build script: https://github.com/Integralist/RequireJs-Example/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/app.build.js it chokes on locating jQuery, and gives the following error...

```
Error: Error: Error evaluating module "undefined" at location "/Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/project-build/Assets/Scripts/jquery.js":
Error: EBADF, Bad file descriptor '/Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/project-build/Assets/Scripts/jquery.js'
fileName:/Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/project-build/Assets/Scripts/jquery.js
lineNumber: undefined
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#defineerror
In module tree:
    main
        App/people

at Function.onError (/Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/Assets/Scripts/r.js:7341:23)
at execManager (/Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/Assets/Scripts/r.js:592:28)
at /Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/Assets/Scripts/r.js:620:25
at execManager (/Users/stormcreative/Dropbox/Library/JavaScript/Libraries/RequireJs/Assets/Scripts/r.js:597:17)
```

...any ideas on how I can fix this? It appears to be trying to find jQuery in the main `/Assets/Scripts/` folder but it's actually in `/Assets/Scripts/Utils/jquery.js`

Look forward to your help.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set the paths config on the `app.build.js` as well, the optimizer doesn't parse the `require.config()` settings contained inside the modules, it increases the flexibility of the build tool, you can easily swap modules during build or not include a module by passing the *special* module path `"empty:"`.

if you look at the error message you will see that it is trying to locate jquery at `/Assets/Scripts/jquery.js` while the correct path is `/Assets/Scripts/Utils/jquery.js`.

cheers.

Comment: I think you mean "empty:". That colon makes all the difference.